# Aerobic rating of a person

Tags: calculus

The aerobic rating of a person $x$ years old is modeled by the function...

$$A(x)= \dfrac{110(\ln(x)-2)}{x}, \quad x \geq 10$$

a) At what age is a person aerobic rating largest?"
b) What is the aerobic rating for a person your age?

I get how to do letter a however, I have no idea what to do for part b. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Why is there a $t$ as the argument of $A$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
A(x) &= 110 {\log(x)-2\over x} \qquad x\geq10
\end{align}

You said you know how to do (A). Which is essentially setting the derivative to $0$ and making sure that the optimal point does indeed satisfy $x\geq10$. If you work this out, the answer is:

> $e^3\approx 20.09$

For part (B).  You just have to put $x=$ Your Age. Suppose your age is $21$.

Your rating would be:

\begin{align}
A(x) &= 110 {\log(21)-2\over 21}
\end{align}

(I am assuming you ARE over 10 years old)

Answer (score 0):

For part b, you subtitute your own age for the variable $x$ and calculate the value of the function $A(x)$.